# Why doesn't it say I win when I do in rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock?

Tags: javascript, html

My game works fine except when I win when lizard or spock is involved, I can't figure out why because when I lose it displays that I lose which is correct. I tried to look for typos but couldn't find any. If anyone can see what's wrong I'd appreciate it.

Here is a fiddle so you can see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5RGwv/

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="center">

<button id="button" onclick="play()">Play</button>
<p>You rolled:</p><span id="myroll"></span>
<p>Your opponent rolled:</p><span id="opproll"></span>

<p id="outcome"></p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function play() {

var ROCK = 0;
var PAPER = 1;
var SCISSORS = 2; 
var LIZARD = 3;
var SPOCK = 4;

var choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors', 'lizard', 'spock'];

var myRoll = Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length);
var opponentRoll = Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length);

document.getElementById("myroll").innerHTML=choices[myRoll];
document.getElementById("opproll").innerHTML=choices[opponentRoll];

if (myRoll == opponentRoll) {
document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML="It's a draw.";
return;
} //end of if

switch(myRoll) {

case ROCK:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == SCISSORS ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
    return;

case ROCK:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == LIZARD ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
    return;

case PAPER: 
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == ROCK ? 'You     win!' : 'You lose!');
    return;

case PAPER:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == SPOCK ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
    return;

case SCISSORS:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == PAPER ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
    return;

case SCISSORS:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == LIZARD ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
    return;

case LIZARD:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == SPOCK ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
    return;

case LIZARD:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == PAPER ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
    return;

case SPOCK:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == SCISSORS ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
    return;

case SPOCK:
    document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == ROCK ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
    return;

} //end of switch(myRoll)


} //end of play()
```

Comment: looks lyk v a big bang theory fan

Comment: "I can't figure out why because when I lose it displays that I lose which is correct." Than what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Wanted to add more elements than rock, paper, scissors. So this would be a good way to do it :P

Comment: In you switch the options appear multiple times. JS will just execute the first finding and omit the others.

Comment: @PeeHaa the problem is in the topic, it doesn't display that I win when I do.

Comment: @Sirko so how would I fix it?

Comment: Combine the different `case` commands for the same case into one and then use an `if` to distinguish further.

Comment: @Sirko is this the way I would write it?  case ROCK:
  document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == SCISSORS ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
 if (opponentRoll == LIZARD) {
  document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML=(opponentRoll == LIZARD ? 'You win!' : 'You lose!');
 }
 return;

Comment: @DuploW Take a look at the given answer. From a first glance, this is pretty much, what I meant.

Comment: @Sirko I tried what u said and my code worked like a charm. Big thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623331/rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `switch` statement with this:

```
var result = false;
switch(myRoll) {
    case ROCK:
        result = opponentRoll == SCISSORS || opponentRoll == LIZARD;
        break;
    case PAPER: 
        result = opponentRoll == ROCK     || opponentRoll == SPOCK;
        break;
    case SCISSORS:
        result = opponentRoll == PAPER    || opponentRoll == LIZARD;
        break;
    case LIZARD:
        result = opponentRoll == SPOCK    || opponentRoll == PAPER;
        break;
    case SPOCK:
        result = opponentRoll == SCISSORS || opponentRoll == ROCK;
        break;
}

document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = result ?  'You win!' : 'You lose!';
```

This piece of code uses the `switch` *only*  to check if you won, or not. Then, at the end the value is set.

Since you win if you roll 'rock' and the opponent rolls 'scissors' OR 'lizard', I combined those statements.

You could shorten the code even more, by just checking for `win` cases, like this:

```
var result =  myRoll == ROCK     && (opponentRoll == SCISSORS || opponentRoll == LIZARD) ||
              myRoll == PAPER    && (opponentRoll == ROCK     || opponentRoll == SPOCK)  ||
              myRoll == SCISSORS && (opponentRoll == PAPER    || opponentRoll == LIZARD) ||
              myRoll == LIZARD   && (opponentRoll == PAPER    || opponentRoll == SPOCK)  ||
              myRoll == SPOCK    && (opponentRoll == ROCK     || opponentRoll == SCISSORS);

document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML = result ?  'You win!' : 'You lose!';
```

If any of those 5 lines is `true`, you've won.

Comment: Replace `return` with `break` or you will never reach the end of the statement

Comment: I went with an if statement but I'm sure this would also work so gonna accept it as an answer.

Comment: @DuploW: thanks! As usual, there's multiple ways to code something, just go with whatever is most convenient for you :)

Comment: Was easier to add a simple if statement than changing the whole Case :P